volume control circuit design to tolerate dirty pots
In an answer to a question about circuit design for audio volume controls, user @Neil_UK suggests this circuit:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
which gives near-log behavior across almost 40 dB when the pot is greater than 10%, and then asks

see if you can [explain] why it doesn't crackle

and ... I really have no idea why it wouldn't crackle if the pot were dirty.
I've found some diy stomp box and tube amp forums where they talk about DC currents across the wiper making dirty pots crackle, which I get (especially if the DC bias is large compared to the signal).
What I don't understand is, if there were no DC bias, but a 1V to -1V peak to peak signal across the wiper and the wiper crosses a dirty part of the track why the sudden drops from 1V to 0V and then back to 1V in the AC signal wouldn't sound like crackle?

It doesn't crackle because negative feedback cancels the crackle.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Spoiler alert.
The op-amp will boost its output to until it can cancel the input signal, boosing sufficiently to overcome the contact resistance. The output of the volume control only sees signal on the same side of the potentiometer as the as the op-amps summing node, so the crackle is also cancelled from the output.

Very interesting circuit!
I agree with Jasen's answer, but here is a more throughout explanation of how it works:

The opamp is connected in negative feedback, so we can assume that voltage on its negative terminal is close to the positive terminal (which is connected to ground). Therefore the input current is Iin = Vin / R2.
The feedback current must match the input current, as no significant current goes into the opamp. This current goes through the first half of the potentiometer. Let's mark potentiometers position by P, so that P = 1 is with the wiper fully to the left.
The resistance in feedback path is then R1 × (1 - P). The wiper voltage is therefore Vwiper = - Iin × R1 × (1 - P).
Output voltage comes through the second half of the potentiometer. Putting together the equations gives:
$$\mathrm{V_{out} = V_{wiper} \times \frac{R3}{R3 + R1 \times P}}$$
$$\mathrm{= - V_{in} \times \frac{R1 \times (1 - P)}{R2} \times \frac{R3}{R3 + R1 \times P}}$$
$$\mathrm{= - V_{in} \times \frac{1 - P}{1 + 6.66 \times P}}$$
The output voltage does not depend on the wiper contact resistance as long as the opamp remains within its voltage swing. However if the contact resistance is too large, the opamp output will get limited by supply voltage before it can reach equilibrium. This will cause distortion or clipping on the output, which will be audible. It probably won't sound like regular potentiometer crackle.
The result is indeed close to logarithmic. It matches the form of the first degree artanh-derived logarithm approximation. Different scaling results in adjustment of the logarithm base and better optimizes it to the P=0..1 range.
$$\mathrm{ln(x) \approx 2 \times \frac{x-1}{x + 1}}$$
